# Inno Setup atalho área de trabalho via código

Tags: inno-setup

Eu gostaria de criar um atalho na área de trabalho via código pelo inno setup eu preciso desativar a opção para criar um "exe" na pasta principal e fica desabilitado para por atalho na área de trabalho e preciso de por via código.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,

Utilizando o inno setup eu crio icone de área de trabalho, seguindo como exemplo o código abaixo. No meu caso onde está escrito "Systec Smart" é o nome que eu quero que fique.

```
[Icons]
;cria no menu iniciar
Name: "{userdesktop}\Systec Smart"; Filename: "{app}\Systec\SystecSmart\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFilename: "{app}\Systec\SystecSmart\{#MyAppExeName}";         Parameters: "SystecSmart.exe"; Comment: "Systec Smart"
```

Espero ter ajudado!